# Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(0)=f(1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(0)=f(1)$. The question asks to give a specific example of $f$ such that: for all $a,b \in [0,1]$ that satisfy $|a-b|=\frac {2}{5}$, $f(a)\ne f(b)$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: The OP is saying that *if* $a,b\in[0,1]$ and $|a-b|=\frac 25$ *then* $f(a)\ne f(b)$. I do not see an answer but I also do not see a proof of impossibility.

Comment: Yep, I misread that badly.

Answer (score 4):

One systematic way to do this is to find such a function satisfying:
$$f\left(x+\frac{2}5\right)=f(x)+1$$
Once you've defined it over the interval $[0,\frac{2}5]$ the rest of the values can be found from this relation. The only constraints on $f$ in that interval will be that $f(\frac{1}5)=f(1)-2=f(0)-2$ and that $f(\frac{2}5)=f(0)=1$. Any continuous $f$ satisfying those and subject to the relation above is an example. This approach gives us examples for any chord length $|a-b|$ other than $\frac{1}n$ (where no examples exist).

An explicit example is $f(x)=\frac{5}4\cos(5\pi x)+\frac{5}2x$ which originates from the recurrence above by choosing a suitable periodic function, adding a multiple of $x$ to get the desired increase, and then setting the wave's amplitude appropriately to get the ends to line up.